# How to return friendly field names for zapier trigger (zapier developers)

Tags: zapier

I am working on a Zapier integration for an online form builder. Each unique form for our users has lots of long, auto-generated field names.

We have a trigger called “New form entries”, which polls our server for form entries, and comes back like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "6209aee326baa600224d822c",
        "email_907058157108782": "test@test.com",
        "phone_589083232390193": "12345",
    },
    {
        "id": "61fd629f19408200225e1893",
        "email_907058157108782": "test@test2.com",
        "phone_589083232390193": "54321",
    },
]
```

However, this results in end users seeing these really long, gross field names in the Zapier interface:

[image: Text]

My question: how do I get Zapier to display friendly labels to the user, whilst using the unique field IDs behind the scenes?

I’m thinking of returning something like the following (each object represents a form entry, , but I need to know how to actually use “friendlyFieldName” and “value” in Zapier!-

```
[
    {
        // the id for the entry
        "id": "62179ec5ab9daa0022df7d1d",
        // the id for the first field entry
        "text_576692390099896": {
            // a friendly name and value for zapier
            "friendlyFieldName": "What is your favourite colour?",
            "value": "Blue"
        }
    }
]
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define output fields labels in `outputFields`. Here are the reference document that you can follow: [Output Fields](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/master/packages/cli/README.md#output-fields)